# how to design a game web app?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i know vb.net, but have had no experience at all with web programming. i need to make a web app that can run in a browser where there is a board game and pieces that you can move around. can someone help me get started? are there any examples in asp.net?

i need something like this:

http://www.hallofbrightcarvings.com/game/grid

i don't know what language this is built in, but i would much prefer vb.net. i would like the pieces to be pictures instead of text. please help get started.

Comment: This site is typically for more specific questions, so I recommend you rephrase your query and put in a few more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a very basic example of moving pieces around a grid written in javascript.
You can see it in action [here](http://www.hallofbrightcarvings.com/game/grid) and if you take a look at the source you can see it's done with jquery mostly. Feel free to take a prod around, I haven't updated that version in a long time but hopefully you might find it useful.

Comment: hey! this is a beautiful example. where can i see the code for this? is it possible to place pictures there instead of text?

Comment: you can see the code (html,css,javascript) by right clicking on the page and choosing "View Source".

Answer (score 2):

I think ASP.NET can do very little for you according to what you described. What you need is either Flash or Javascript skills.

Comment: That's not quite true. Such a game could be built easily enough with AJAX (which would of course involve JavaScript). Silverlight is another good option, given that the question is .NET-oriented.

Comment: i dont know anything about ajax? can someone help me decide whether it is suitable for my project, and if so, how do i build programs with ajax? what is silverlight and how do i use it?

Comment: @Noldorin I'm not so sure if you need AJAX (or any other means to communicate with the web server). If you look at the example @alex posted it's all javascript (using jquery). I do agree with your Silverlight suggestion though, I personally think it's a much more developer friendly options compared to Flash.

Comment: @alex checkout jquery (http://jquery.com), it's a very nice javascript library and very popular among ASP.NET developers these days. ASP.NET MVC even ships with it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose this, you need two things if you want to make the whole thing yourself

- Client Side: Flash, SilverLight, JAVA
- Server Side:PHP, ASP.net, Java

As you know vb.net and want to work with asp.net, so I recommand to use Silverlight.

**How complex can this be?**

Depends on what you want to build, if you want to build a Mafia war games, then you'll need to work the user interface and it'll be very hard. Also the server side will be important as you need to handle registration and relation between different players.

If you specify more your question, you could get better answers.

Comment: Flash has way more market penetration than Silverlight...this may or may not be a problem, depending on the OP's needs, but if you need it to "just work" for members of the public, Flash is a much better choice, simply because of the install base.

Comment: i just need a very simple baord like this one: http://www.hallofbrightcarvings.com/game/grid with pictures that the user can move around

Answer (score 1):

The example you cited above is fully client-side, which means the code all sits on the browser and the server doesn't do anything to enable the grid. So if you did a "Save As" of that page on your computer, you could run it offline.

You should use the view source functionality of your browser on the page you cited, and look at how it's built. It's done using HTML, CSS and javascript. Use w3schools to get yourself started on those three matters.

If you really need to code it using vb.net, I don't know of any way that allows drag-and-drop for web forms. I'd be interested to know though. Ajax and .net drag-and-drop should be keywords for you to look into.

Answer (score 0):

To do this on the web, you'd probably want to divide the project into two components: Client-side and server-side.

On the server-side, you'll want to use language like PHP, Python or ASP.NET. I think ASP.NET has some way to use VB.NET, so that would be a good choice for you to minimize the number of new things you need to learn.

Client-side is going to be the big hurdle. There's basically two different approaches to take here:

- HTML+CSS+Javascript, using HTTP callbacks (ie, AJAX) to communicate with the server.
- Flash using [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) (I think HTTP calls is probably the easiest way to talk to your server here as well.)

For a game like that, I would think that Flash is probably the best way to go. It will be easier to do graphics and sounds, and it'll run the same in every browser that has Flash support.

Comment: jason, is there a free flash creation program i can download? can u show me any examples of flash "game boards"

Comment: You can download a trail of Flex Builder for free at Adobe's site. Keep in mind that I made that recommendation based on an assumption that there would be a fair amount of interactivity, heavy (for the web) use of animation and sound. If those things are not true of your project, a JS frontend might be a better choice.